# How do i restore data onclick in laravel and vuejs?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I try to make a button that restores previous data from textarea how do I do that in laravel and vuejs.I submit the data with vuejs axios then return it modify, I try to make a button that restores previous data in textarea.

html

```
<div id="root">
    <textarea v-model="areamodel" name="textarea" class="form-control" rows="10" id="textarea"></textarea>
    <button v-on:click="vanila" class="btn btn-md btn-info ">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-transfer"></span> Restore
    </button>
</div>
```

controller laravel

```
public function vue(Request $request)
{
    $vanila = $request->get('areamodel');

    return response()->json(['vanila' => $vanila]);
}
```

and vuejs

```
new Vue({
    el: '#root',
    data: {
        areamodel: '',
    },

    methods: {
        vanila: function () {
            this.vanila = data.areamodel;
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: done now is better